# Possible to use multiple ionic version in same app

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is it possible to use ionic 1 and ionic 2 with the same app?
I have one application it created in ionic 1 framework i need to create another new model for this project, plan to create this model using ionic 2.

Whether is it possible to maintain 2 different ionic version in same application?

Comment: So just a section of the app will be created in Ionic 2 ?

Comment: yes, i expect this feature